# Drupal 6: best way to upgrade jQuery?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6

I want to upgrade jQuery inside my drupal installation. At the moment I have jQuery 1.2.6 and I would like to upgrade it to jQuery 1.4

I guess some Drupal modules still depends on the old jQuery version. I've tried jquery_update module to upgrade jQuery, but it didn't work. It asked to replace the original Drupal files in the "misc" folder with the new ones, but it didn't work.

Anyway, I was wondering if there is a better method instead of using another module

thanks

Comment: When you say you replaced the file and it didn't work.  What exactly didn't work?

Comment: maybe consider changing your accepted answer because it seems that manually updating the jquery.js file may cause a lot of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the jquery update module doesn't install jquery 1.4. you need to manually update the jquery.js.

Comment: so, I should use jquery update module and then manually download jquery 1.4 and overwrite the old one ?

Comment: yeah, that's the best way for now.

Comment: you can't just replace jquery.js with a newer version and expect it to work!  ahah, draggables and a bunch of other stuff will break!

Answer (score 10):

jQuery 1.4 breaks quite a few ajax bits in the admin UI, which are pretty essential. Luckily you can get around this by loading a different version of jQuery depending on what page you are currently viewing.

I recommend using the jQuery update module and modifying it with one of the solutions here (#7 or #11):

http://drupal.org/node/775924

Answer (score 5):

A very nice solution is the following, especially for people who do not feel very comfortable patching any part of drupal.

The author provides a clean way of running the default jquery version and any other version (of your choice) - side by side.

http://drupal.org/node/1058168

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [jQuery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module

Comment: I've not had any trouble with jQuery Update, if you do you should report the bugs to the modules that don't work with it.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up creating my own solution based on a couple discussions on Drupal.org

It's available on GitHub and works 100% with Drupal/Pressflow 6 and jQuery 1.5.2

https://github.com/alexweber/jquery_update