# Jquery and Regex help needed

Tags: jquery, regex

Here's HTML

```
  <div id="taxonomylist">
  <div class="item-list"><ul><li class="first"><a href="/?q=category/activity/energy" class="views-processed">Energy</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/energy/3-5" class="views-processed">3-5</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/energy/6-8" class="views-processed">6-8</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/energy/k-2" class="views-processed">K-2</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/forestry" class="views-processed">Forestry</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/forestry/3-5" class="views-processed">3-5</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/forestry/6-8" class="views-processed">6-8</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/forestry/k-2" class="views-processed">K-2</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/mining" class="views-processed">Mining</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/mining/3-5" class="views-processed">3-5</a></li>
<li><a href="/?q=category/activity/mining/6-8" class="views-processed">6-8</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="/?q=category/activity/mining/k-2" class="views-processed">K-2</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

I need to hide all elements inside div except those that says THIS. I need to keep that one.
So as for regex parsing - i need it to show only those values that: 
1. Start with anything
2. then have structure: structure /activity/"anything here"/"nothing here"
You can see what I mean by looking on the code above.

Flow of my logic
1. hide all li elements within particular div
2. if 'a' element inside li contains attribute href which is equal to /title/ then show this li element. My current code

```
$('li').css('display','none');
if ($('li').attr('href')=="*/activity/*/")
{
$('li').css('display','block');
}
```

if I do something like:

```
$('#div-id li').css('display','none');
```

then it does not work.
Im just tired, but need to finish work asap. help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it solves your problem:

```
$("div#div-id li").each(function() {
  var href = $("a", this).attr("href");
  if ( href.match(/^.*\/activity\/.*\/$/i) ) {
       alert($(this).text());
  }
});
```

Check a demo at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ozive4/2/edit

**UPDATE:** It was just a basic principle. Here is something more complete:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  function get() {
    $("div#div-id li").each(function() {
      var href = $("a", this).attr("href");
      if ( href.match(/^.*\/activity\/.*\/$/i) ) {
           alert($(this).text());
      }
    });
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    get();
  });
});
```

And the demo: http://jsbin.com/ozive4/4/edit

**UPDATE:** This is the regex:

```
/^.\/activity\/.[a-z,A-Z]$/i
```

And the new demo: http://jsbin.com/ozive4/6/edit

Comment: Thanks. I put my own html and it didn't work. Can you check please? http://jsbin.com/ozive4/3/edit

Comment: @user194076 The href's you wanna keep doens't end with a trailing slash as they did in the first example code. The regex has to be adjusted. Gimme a minute and I'll try do fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

```
if ($('li').attr('href').match(/.*\/activity\/.*\/$/m)) {
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I meant. Thanks on that one.

Comment: That still won't fix all problems though -- with the rest of the code that's in the question, if any match, all will be shown.

Comment: How Do I access inner elements of nested divs? Thanks!

Comment: you can use $('#div-id .div-class ul li').html()

Comment: This match thing matches everything. Unfortunately. Cannot find an error

Comment: It matches everything because there isn't a $ to signal "end of string". This got me at first too when I was creating my own answer, but adding the ^ and $ to signal the beginning and end of the string got things going.

Comment: i updated my answer a few minutes ago but for some reason my comment didn't show up

Answer (score 2):

Using [James Padolsey's RegEx filter](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/), I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EUk8q/9/) that hides the ones that don't match your pattern. Aside from the RegEx filter, the relevant code is

```
     $('a:regex(href, .*/activity/.*/.*)').closest('li').hide();
```

EDIT: I changed to .hide(); from a .each() that set display:none. Must be getting late, not sure why I did it the long way originally :)

EDIT 2: Updated jsfiddle from version 7  to version 9.

Comment: @user194076-have you tried my solution...even i have given you demo for the same

Comment: @Vivek, yours makes the decision based on the contents of the text. The user wants to make the decision based on the pattern of the href.

Comment: @user194076 Did you include the RegEx filter code when you tried it? I omitted it from this post, but you can get it by clicking through.

Comment: @user194076 You can also click through to the jsfiddle link to see the entire script and its results.

Comment: @user194076 Do you agree that the Results panel on the jsfiddle shows the correct three elements and hides the others?

Comment: @user194076  Can you post the list item hrefs it fails on?

Comment: I've just edited html part to reflect my actual html in my post.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem. Your description and original examples said there should be a slash before "nothing here", but your actual values don't have that trailing /. Give me a minute.

Comment: Energy, Mining and Forestry do not have ending /'s

Comment: Exactly. The original examples did, and the jsfiddle relied on that. If you add those trailing slashes, the existing jsfiddle code would work as demonstrated in the jsfiddle itself.

Comment: New jsfiddle and code in my edit seems to work with the new example

Comment: i think i have some problems with my head. Everything works in jsfiddle, but not on my machine. Although some of the jquery functions work fine. Thanks a lot for your effort. I am going to do something..I don't know

Comment: @user194076 What version of jQuery are you loading and when/where relative to this code?

Comment: i'm not sure what version of jquery drupal uses but it is drupal 6

Comment: Well, I'm not too familiar with Drupal but I've seen some posts that 6 might use jQuery 1.2.6? My jsfiddle uses 1.4.4. Maybe check the following SO question on how to upgrade jQuery in Drupal, and good luck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713315/drupal-6-best-way-to-upgrade-jquery

Answer (score 1):

for hiding all li except **THIS** you can use this code...

```
  $('div.div-class ul li').hide();


$(' ul li').each(function(){

    if($(this).text()=="THIS")
        $(this).show();

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eskLc/)

Comment: There can be anytext unfortunately