# JQuery local mock vs. remote system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am afraid I similar question might be already asked somewhere, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Here's roughly my environement + purpose:
I have a very simple HTML JQuery Setup whose intent is do collapse the later content when a page has more than 5 h3's. Each h3 is followed by 1 or more paragraphs. If a page does have more than 5 h3's every content belonging to the h3 should be automatically collapsed (hidden), shown when the corresponding h3 is clicked and hidden, when clicked again.

Here's my **jquery** code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($('h3').length > 4) {
    var headlines = $('h3').slice(3);
    var start = $('h3').slice(3,4);     
    var content = start.nextAll().not('h6');

    headlines.addClass('expandable-headline');
    content.hide(); 

    headlines.click(function() {        
        var successors = $(this).nextUntil('h3');
        successors.toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('expandable-headline');
    }); 
}
});
```

Here's my **html**:

```
< h3>ABC</h3 >  
< p>some nice content</p >
< h3>ABC</h3>
< p>some nice content</p>
< p>some even nicer content</p>
```

Last but not least, here's my problem:

All code above works perfect when run locally in simple test files, but when I try it inside my production system (a Drupal site) it throwns an error at

```
 var successors = $(this).nextUntil('h3');
```

stating, that **$(this).nextUntil is not a function**.

Any ideas, what this is about?

I appreciate any help.
Best Greeets,
Sunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your versions of jQuery the same?

To test this, insert this line of code somewhere into your script on each page:

```
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

It'll `alert()` your version number.

If your search [the jQuery changelog](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/) for `nextUntil`, you'll see that it was added in version **1.4**, so your Drupal jQuery version might be old.

If you are planning on upgrading jQuery (I don't use Drupal. Wordpress works fine for me), this question seems relevant: [Drupal 6: best way to upgrade jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713315/drupal-6-best-way-to-upgrade-jquery).

Comment: And while you're changing versions, this is a great opportunity to load JQuery from the CDN, which is faster than serving it from your own server.  See here:  http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Comment: Is there a constantly-updated version (this might be impossible due to caching), like `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/current/jquery.min.js`? It would be nice to just shove that into my `<head>` tag and not worry about updates...

Comment: agreed, would be nice, but there is actually a benefit to that not happening.  As an example, JQuery UI is about to change the way some elements work.  As a result, the next version will support the new and the old methods, with the following version deprecating the old method.  Most (all) of us now have code that will be deprecated.  So, if it was to be automatic, one day all our stuff using JQuery UI would break, and that'd be bad.  I just schedule on my calendar monthly checks to each piece of open source software, which has worked great so far.

Comment: Thanks. As of now, the different version of jq seem to be the origin of my issue. Who would have known, that the Drupal jquery update module doesn't do the trick of updating jquery. Certainly some people do - me didn't.

Thanks for you help Blender! Codesnippet and links.

Comment: When I use jQuery, it's pretty subtle; an effect here and there, nothing too crucial to the design of the site. But I didn't think about jQuery UI, as that seems to be evolving pretty quickly. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a versioning problem?

nextUntil was added in v1.4, so if your Drupal system is referencing an older version of jQuery, that'd be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you aren't including multiple jquery files on the page.  Some drupal modules insert their own jquery libraries into page that they are used on and if they aren't the correct version, the jquery object you are referencing might be overwritten and be the reason why the page isn't working.