# .info file not loading javascript drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I added these script tags to my .info file in hopes that they would be output by the $scripts variable in my header. I cleared my cache and they are still not there.

```
$Id$
name = site
base theme = boron
core = 6.x
engine = phptemplate
; We do not have a Left sidebar.
;regions[left] = Left sidebar
; We do not have a right sidebar.
;regions[right] = Right sidebar
regions[content] = Content
regions[header] = Header
regions[footer] = Footer
scripts[] = sitename/sites/all/themes/custom/jivamukti/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js
scripts[] = sitename/sites/all/themes/custom/jivamukti/js/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
```

I put the JS in the root of the themes folder i am using instead of at /js and now it is output in this function in my header

jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings,...

how do i just get it to display inside  tags

Comment: Closing this as you cross posted the same thing to Drupal SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you're unlikely to get this working, Drupal 6 is not remotely compatible with jQuery 1.6. The highest you can stably go at the moment is 1.3.2 using the [jQuery Update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update).

The best thing you can do is install the jQuery update module, and manually swap out the jQuery library file with version 1.4 (the minimum that Nivo slider requires). There's a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713315/drupal-6-best-way-to-upgrade-jquery) with some more information.

Other than that do what maged adel suggests and change the paths so that they're relative to the location of the `.info` file, not the server root.

**UPDATE**

There's a very good [post on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/775924) with an extended discussion on the subject.

Comment: what do you mean by manually switch out? If it only updates to 1.3.2 why use the update module?

Comment: Because it lays the groundwork to auto-replace Drupal's core jQuery library without you having to do any extra work. By manually switch out I mean simply replace the jQuery file included with jquery_update module with jQuery 1.4. The link to the Drupal.org post has everything you need to know in it :)

Answer (score 3):

can you try this

```
scripts[] = js/scripts/test.js
scripts[] = js/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
scripts[] = js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js
```

and insert this test code inside your test.js file

```
jQuery.ready(startfunction) ; 
function startfunction() {
  alert("hellooo") ; 
}
```

then clear the cache

Comment: This was one thing i was doing wrong with the relative paths, but the post below solved my problem with JQuery version.